# jQueryMobile Change listview's item attributes dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-attributes

I want to change dynamically (click event) a data-theme of a list item in a jQueryMobile listview. Firebug shows me that the change is performed but the list is not refreshed. (If I add elements it works, but with attribute changes the list won't be refreshed.) For example I want to change the data-theme from c to f when the item is clicked.

I tried everything I read in this forum, from trigger('mouseout') over trigger('create') on parents to refreshing the whole page, but no effect at all, so I guess I am blind to see something obvious. Maybe somebody can give me a hint... :)

```
<script>

function fillList() {
    var li = '<li data-theme="c"><a href="#" class="info">List item</a></li>';
    $("#alist").empty().append(li).promise().done(function () {
        $(this).off("click").on("click", ".info", function (e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var theLiElem = $(this).closest('li');
            theLiElem.attr('data-theme','f').trigger('mouseout');
            theLiElem.trigger("create");
        });
        $(this).listview("refresh");
    });
}

$(document).on("pageinit", "#info-page", function () {
    fillList();
});

</script>

<div data-role="page" id="info-page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="alist" data-inset="true">
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Kind regards,

Steve

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AFfw9/

Comment: Hello Omar! Thank you for the fast reply. Except that I want to add dynamically also the list items (yes, I should have noted in the question) it is was I was looking for.

But even your example in jsfiddle did not work in my environment, and I think I found the reason: It works well with jquery mobile 1.3.0 with jQuery core 1.9.1, but in my combination jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 with jQuery core 2.0.3 it is not working.

Comment: Because there are many changes in JQM 1.4 pls post more details in your question and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have looked around in other forums and now I know that with 1.4 there are lots of things changed that I did not expect. It is now supposed to theme buttons (and listview items that are technically buttons) using CSS classes, not data-theme. "data-theme" will be removed completely in a future version. So, I should start using the CSS classes instead of data-theme, if I want to continue with JQM 1.4+. In 1.4.x any data-theme added after widget initialization is just ignored. It's no longer used (for buttons) in the CSS.

Thanks again, Omar, for your support!

Comment: Note that data-theme is still essential for page's main parts, i.e. Header, footer, panel, popup, especially the external ones. Good luck and feel free to ask more questions.